# How to Retrieve more than 10K records in Elasticsearch through SpringBoot API

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to generate a Report from fetching the data from ElasticSearch through Spring boot API.
So I need to fetch more than 40K records from Elasticsearch. How can I retrieve all of the results/data in only one GET API?

Please can anybody provide me an example or solution or guide/suggest me, how can I retrieve all the data for a GET search query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get this number of rows in a single http call.

You should use the `search_after` API, as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

1. You query ES with a sort field
2. ES will return hits and for each hit, a sort value
3. You can then make a request with a `serch_after` referencing a sort value

To be consistent between each page, you can also use a PIT (Point in time).

To be honest, there is a workaround to get more then 10k, but it's really not recommanded, as you will increase the memory requirement for each request. It's just a property in the ES configuration (`index.max_result_window`)